# Strange error : Cannot find Tree type for class

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, sylius

when I run this command `php app/console doctrine:generate:form AcmeMyBundle:StudentUser`, I get this error :

```
 [Gedmo\Exception\InvalidMappingException]

 Cannot find Tree type for class: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\Taxon
```

Any Idea?

**EDIT** :

Ok I don't think so that error have an relationship with StudentUser,because the same thing with all entities :

```
namespace APP\Bundle\FrontBundle\Entity;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use PUGX\MultiUserBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\User;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Bundle\FrontBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="sylius_user_student")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = "username", targetClass = "Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\User", message="fos_user.username.already_used")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = "email", targetClass = "Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\User", message="fos_user.email.already_used")
 */
class StudentUser extends User
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="package_name", type="string", length=100)
 */
protected $package_name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="students_available", type="string", length=100)
 */
protected $studens_available;
```

....

Comment: You have something wrong on your StudentUser entity. Can you paste the entity?

Comment: I don't think so but I added the StudentUser entity in edit in my first message,tnks.

Comment: you are right. your entity seems fine. the problem is on Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Model\Taxon but this class doesn't exist on the Sylius Repository https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusCoreBundle/tree/master/spec/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Model

Comment: Sorry you don't know anything about my issues

Comment: Update your vendor folder...

Answer (score 0):

I must be an error from Sylius Bundle, 
When this error happens i means that this entity must have in the class notations

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class Service
{
}
```

Because some of the properties are using Gedmo notations like

```
 @Gedmo\TreeLevel,  @Gedmo\TreeRight
```

Example:

```
 /**
 * @Gedmo\TreeLeft
 * @ORM\Column(name="lft", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
 private $lft;
```

So you could override that entity and correct the mistake.

I wish i could help.